# Credit Card Offer Wording?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, spending

I saw an adv for a credit card that I liked the benefits on. The [Chase Freedom Unlimited](https://creditcards.chase.com/a1/freedom-unlimited) card (in the US) will do exactly what I need it to at a reasonable APR, but some of the wording really confused me.

On top of the benefits that I think will really help me, it says

> EARN A $150 BONUS after you spend $500 on purchases
>   in your first 3 months from account opening.*

Does this mean that I spend $500 over a 3 month period, or $500 **per month** for 3 months?

I'm just a little confused by the wording.

Comment: $500 total within 3 months of the day you apply/get approved

Comment: @VBCPP Answers should be posted as answers, not put in the comments.

Comment: @BenMiller I don't think it's a very good question so I didn't want to take the time to write a formal answer.

Comment: What do you need to do with a "reasonable APR?"

Comment: @quid Finance purchases on that rather than my high APR card. It'll save money in the long run when I'm paying 19% rather than 28% APR.

Comment: Well if you're doing that you should look at the Chase Slate (I know we're not supposed to make product suggestions) but its 0% balance transfer fee 0% interest for 15 months right now.  There are no rewards but if you're paying interest you're better off with no interest than a percent or two cash back.

Comment: @quid That's the OTHER card I have. ;) I'm working on getting strictly to Chase cards but I started with a CapitalOne card. The new card has rewards (something I like), and I can use my slate card for different purchases and holding onto larger balances for longer term financing.

Comment: Just a tip, if the 500 $ is pushing your limits, you can buy giftcards for it, and spend those over time afterwards.

Comment: @Aganju That's a great tip! In reality, the $500 wouldn't push my limits at all. We saved up well over $500 to buy some badly needed furniture, but if it was $500 each for 3 months, that'd really be stretching us thin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Chase I can confirm that it's $500 during the first three months.  Typically the clock starts running on that three months the day you are approved, not the day you activate the card.  Also with Chase, the credit occurs in whichever month the criteria is met.  Some banks wait until the initial period is exhausted to determine whether bonus criteria was met then issue the credit or points or whatever.

Generally these sign up bonuses refer to an initial time period of three to six months, not a monthly minimum spend in each month.